# EAV vs null vs Mixed

Tags: mysql, product, entity-attribute-value

I'm familar with normalized databases and I'm able to produce all kind of queries. But since i'm starting on a green-field project now, one question kept me busy during this week:

It's the typical "webshop-problem" i'd say (even if i'm not building a webshop): How to model the "product-information"?

There are some approaches, each with its own advantages or disadvantages:

### One Table to rule them all

Putting every "product" into a single table, generating every column possible and working with this monster-table.

Pro:

- Easy queries
- Easy layout

Con:

- Lot of NULL Values
- The actual code becomes sensitive towards the query (different type, different columns are required)

### EAV-Pattern

Obviously the EAV-Pattern can provide a nicer solution for this. However, I've been working with EAV in the past, and when it comes down to performance, it can become a Problem for a huge amount of entries.

Searching is easy, but listing a "normalized table" requires one join per actual column -> slow.

Pro:

- Clean
- Flexible

Con:

- Performance
- Not Normalized

### Single Table per category

Basically the opposite of the EAV-Pattern: Create one table per product-type, i.e. "cats", "dogs", "cars", ...

While this might be possible for a countable number of categories, it becomse a nightmare for a steady growing amount of categories, if you have to maintain those.

Pro:

- Clean
- Performance

Con:

- Maintenance
- Query-Management

### Best of both worlds

So, on my journey through the internet I found recommendations to mix both approaches: Use a single Table for the common information, while grouping other attributes into "attribute-groups" which are organized in the EAV-Fashion.

However, here I think, this would basically import the drawbacks of EACH approach... You need to work with regular Tables (basic information) and do a huge amount of joins to get ALL information.

### Storing enhanced information in JSON/XML

Another approach is to store extendet information in JSON/XML Format entries (within a column of the "root-table").

However, I don't really like this, as it seems hard(er) to query and to work-with than a regular database layout.

### Automating single tables

Another idea was automating the part of "creating tables" per category (and therefore automating the queries on those), while maintaining a "master-table" just containing the id and the category information, in order to get the best performance for an undetermined amount of tables...?

i.e.:

```
Products
id | category | actualId
1  | cat      | 1
2  | car      | 1

cats
id | color | mew
1  | white | true

cars
id | wheels | bhp
1  | 4      | 123
```

the (abstract) Product table would allow to query for everything, while details are available by an easy join with "actualId" and the responsible table.

However, this would lead to problems if you want to run a "show all" query, because this is not solvable by SQL alone, cause the table name (in the join) needs to be explicit in the query.

---

What other Options are available? There are a lot of "webshops", each dealing with this problem more or less - how do they solve it in a efficent way?

Answer (score 0):

I strongly disagree with your opinion that the "monster" table approach leads to "Easy queries", and that the EAV approach will cause performance issues (premature optimization?). And it doesn't have to require complex queries:

```
SELECT base.id, base.other_attributes,
, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCATENATE(ext.key, '[', ext.type, ']',  ext.value)) 
FROM base_attributes base
LEFT JOIN  extended_attributes ext
ON base.id=ext.id
WHERE base.id=?
;
```

You would need to do some parsing on the above, but a wee bit of polishing would give something parseable as JSON or XML *without putting your data inside anonymous blobs*

If you don't care about data integrity and are happy to solve performance via replication, then NoSQL is the way to go (this is really the same thing as using JSON or XML to store your data).

Comment: Thx for this example. Actually the "Get-All-With-One-Join"-approach might be a nice idea to consider, when working with some very "basic" language. (I.e. in PHP there wouldn't be difference after parsing it). However, this approach makes you loose "everything" a type-save-Framwork will provide. Also, when using Hibernate (Java) or EntityFramework (C#) - you won't be able to benefit of auto-generated Models...

Comment: Using factories rather than primitive object relational mapping gives huge savings in the long term even in the absence of polymorphism in my experience.